# Run warden strategy in devise when user is already authenticated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, warden

I'm using devise to authenticate my users via username / password or a couple of OAuth providers. Now I have to support a custom authentication Strategy that uses a token inside a header.

```
module WardenStrategies
  class ApiKey < Warden::Strategies::Base
    def valid?
      api_token.present?
    end

    def authenticate!
      user = User.find_by(api_token: api_token)

      if user
        success!(user)
      else
        fail!("Invalid email or password")
      end
    end

    private

    def api_token
      env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"].to_s.remove("Bearer ")
    end
  end
end
```

I've added the strategy to devise and warden

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ...
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :api_key
  end
  # ...
end
```

```
# config/initializers/warden.rb
Warden::Strategies.add(:api_key, WardenStrategies::ApiKey)
```

The problem now is: I have a playground on the same site that sends requests to my API via JavaScript. In the playground I can provide a custom API key for a different user. **But when the user is already logged in via a normal session, warden doesn't run the strategy any more, because it already has a User assigned.**

So, how can I force warden / devise to try a strategy, even when the user is already authenticated?

Comment: You may just be thinking about this backwards. Warden does't halt "because it already has a User assigned" it halts because the session strategy called `success!` and halted the cascade.  All you really have to do is place your api key strategy before the other stategies. https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden/wiki/Strategies

Comment: @max once some strategy succeeded and stored user into session - no other strategy is run for subsequent requests: [warden/proxy.rb:334](https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden/blob/997055a511ae65b1d0b84112f1f35813e3f4cd84/lib/warden/proxy.rb#L334)

Comment: @Vasfed you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling any strategies warden checks if there's already a stored user in session (from previous requests, where some strategy with `store?`=true (the default) has succeeded)

You can try faking a 'non-set' user (without full log out) by something like:

```rb
# manager is Warden::Manager
manager.prepend_on_request do |proxy|
  proxy.set_user(nil, scope: :user, store: false) if proxy.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"].present?
end
```

PS. your strategy probably should also have `def store?; false; end`, as api keys are usually required with each request, and also should not result in persisted session

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately when I use your snippet I just get an empty instance of user `#<User id: nil, email: nil>` in `request.env["warden"].user` and the `WardenStrategies::ApiKey#valid?` or `WardenStrategies::ApiKey#authenticate!` is not called. Any ideas?

Comment: @23tux try debugging warden proxy `_perform_authentication`, also instead of `nil` you can inject correct user

Comment: I think the `prepend_on_request` callback is triggered BEFORE warden loads the user from the session, because `proxy.user == nil`. I don't want to logout the user, I just want to use another strategy for a single request. Is there a callback where I can intercept loading an user from the session?

Comment: I also looked at `.after_fetch` and `.after_set_user`, and it seems this methods only get called when an actual strategy is performing an authentication. When I debug into `_perform_authentication` it seems that it is not called when no actual authentication is performed.

Comment: I got it to work, by injecting another user in with `proxy.set_user(user, scope: :user, store: false)`. But the problem is, that `warden.winning_strategy` is `nil` because no actual authentication was performed (because the current user is already loaded via session). Is there a way to force a re-authentication in warden?

Comment: I just faced that issue and `def store?; false; end` is the only thing I needed to get it working properly, thank you!